# django update model while saving another form

Tags: django, django-models

I am saving a from and updating another model in the form, but the update is not saved to database.

```
        if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InventoryTransactionForm(request.POST, instance=InventoryTransaction())
        if form.is_valid():                
            quantity = request.POST['quantity']
            part_id = request.POST['part_id']
            item_template_id = request.POST['supply']
            try:
                item_object = Item.objects.get(pk=part_id)
                masterQty = item_object.masterQty - int(quantity)
                item_object.save(force_update=True)
            except Exception, e:                    
                messages.error(request, e.message)
```

can anybody please help what is wrong in above code, thanks.

EDIT: updated code as below

```
    @transaction.commit_manually
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = InventoryTransactionForm(request.POST, instance=InventoryTransaction())
            if form.is_valid():

                quantity = request.POST['quantity']
                part_id = request.POST['part_id']
                item_template_id = request.POST['supply']
                try:
                    item_object = Item.objects.get(pk=part_id)
                    masterQty = item_object.masterQty - int(quantity)

            item_object.save(force_update=True)
                    transaction.commit()
                except Exception, e:                    
                    transaction.rollback()
                    messages.error(request, e.message)  

            form.save(True)
```

Comment: Have you removed the `try...except` to see if an exception is being raised? Is the form definitely valid (i.e. the `if form.is_valid()` is actually `True`)?

Comment: The form is valid, the form model object is created successfully on submission. I will try to remove try....except and see if I get any error thanks

Comment: Hi I removed try...except, the form submits successfully but the model is not updated in database. However I added @transaction.commit_manually, the model is saved in database, but I get error "Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK", any help how to resolve this error, tried searching, but none of the solutions worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`force_update=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#forcing-an-insert-or-update) in the save method. From the docs:

> In some rare circumstances, it’s necessary to be able to force the save() method to perform an SQL INSERT and not fall back to doing an UPDATE. Or vice-versa: update, if possible, but not insert a new row. In these cases you can pass the force_insert=True or force_update=True parameters to the save() method. Obviously, passing both parameters is an error: you cannot both insert and update at the same time!

You are saving the object to the database for the first time so it doesn't make sense to call `force_update=True` as it will prevent the object from being created in the first place. So change

```
item_object.save(force_update=True)
```

to

```
item_object.save()
```

Comment: Hi I am creating the form object ie InventoryTransaction and updating item_object which exists in database.  Please see my updated code. It updates when I use @transaction.commit_manually decorator but I get another error thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is about working with django ORM here.
You get your object from the database here : `item_object = Item.objects.get(pk=part_id)` but you lose the instance of this object when doing `item_object = Item(masterQty=masterQty, item_template_id=item_template_id, id=part_id)`.

That's why you think you need a force update but you actually just need to keep the right instance of your object.

Why don't you just update the fields on the object you got from the db and then save it ?
Like so :

```
item_object = Item.objects.get(pk=part_id)
item_object.masterQty -= int(quantity)
item_object.item_template_id = item_template_id
item_object.save()
```

You don't even need a force update as you'll be working on an instance you got from the db.

Comment: sorry ignore that line, I was trying some solution forgot to delete that line. I tried still the object doesnt get updated. The query "query  {u'time': u'0.001', u'sql': u'QUERY = u\'UPDATE "parts_item" SET "item_template_id" = %s, "masterQty" = %s WHERE "parts_item"."id" = %s\' - PARAMS = (2, 9976, 2)'}
" shows its updated ibut is it not committed in database?

Comment: did you remove the transaction decorator as well ?

Comment: Yes I have removed the transaction decorator, but if I use transaction.commit_manually decorator, the model is updated in database, but I get TransactionManagementError on page reload after commit

Comment: don't commit things yourself, you'll probably never have to use it instead you're in a particular case, let django do it instead.
revert to the code before your edit with the transactions and try putting the code snippet I use in my answer

Comment: Hi tried your snippet, the query shows its updating, but the change is not reflected in database. Is is not committed to database? I think save() auto commits to database. I am updating it in another modelForm form is_valid() method, can it be the cause?

Comment: This code should work, you said yourself that the query is fine. The problem might come from elsewhere. Can you edit your question to show us the code with your is_valid you're talking about ?

Comment: Am not sure whats causing the error. please see my EDIT code above regarding the form. thanks a lot.